# ROS ekf_localization

Tags: ros, navigation, odometry, ros-kinetic, ekf-localization

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

Is there a way to weitgh/gain on input to the ekf_localization_node more than other?

In my case I have wheel odometry and odmetry from an ArUco marker mounted on my robot which is beeing tracked as an odom_msg.

From what I see the ArUco odometry is more accurate than my wheel odometry, how can I make the ekf use the ArUco more than the other?

Thanks in advance

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/319431/ros-ekf_localization/) by [jksllk](https://answers.ros.org/users/40441/jksllk/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2019-03-25

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2019-03-25**:
are you talking about the `ekf_localization_node` of the `robot_localization` [package](http://docs.ros.org/melodic/api/robot_localization/html/state_estimation_nodes.html)?

**Comment by [jksllk](https://answers.ros.org/users/40441/jksllk/) on 2019-03-25**:
Yes, sorry about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes! The covariance matrix that your sensor includes to the input to robot_localization is used, unlike in the prior robot pose ekf. If you make the covariance values of the sensor you want to trust higher, then that will be effectively weighed more.

---

Originally posted by [stevemacenski](https://answers.ros.org/users/25940/stevemacenski/) with karma: 8272 on 2019-03-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jksllk](https://answers.ros.org/users/40441/jksllk/) on 2019-03-26**:
Thank you! I will try it out

**Comment by [stevemacenski](https://answers.ros.org/users/25940/stevemacenski/) on 2019-03-26**:
Please mark this question as answered so that it can be removed from the unanswered questions queue :-)

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2019-03-27**:
@jksilk to makre an answer as correct use the checkbox at the left of the answer instead of changing the title. I've done it for you in this case.